# Memory allocation in case of const static variables in function scope

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, static

In C, what's the difference between a `static const int` and a `const int` in terms of memory alocated?

```
void f(int *a)
{
    static const int b = 10;
    const int c = 20;

    *a = b + c;
}
```

Will `b` only consume `sizeof(int)`? And `c`, will it consume `sizeof(int)` for the `20` value, and `sizeof(int)`, plus a copy instruction during `f` execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that both constants are known inside the function, what's to stop the compiler from making it `*a = 30;`? Neither `b` nor `c` MUST have storage in this example.

If there is storage needed:

```
 static const int b = 10;
```

will take up one sizeof(int) [possibly more space is used due to padding, depends on what comes before and after `a` in the data section, and there is nothing stating how much padding the compiler will provide for any given scenario - whatever is necessary to make things "work" on the system the compiler is targetting]. Depending on the architecture of the system, there may be code required to set b = 10 [see below about the size of that].

```
 const int c = 20;
```

Will possibly take up sizeof(int) bytes on the stack, but there will also be code to initialize `b` to 20 - which could be any small number - 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 16 or some such, depending on processor architecture and the type of instrucitons required to get that job done. Of course, the compiler could just use 20 directly wherever it needs to.

But all that is required by the compiler is that *a is set to 30 some way or another. Everything else is "up to the compiler".

Answer (score 5):

The language standard says nothing about this.

However, it's likely that the compiler will convert your code to this:

```
void f(int *a) {
    *a = 30;
}
```

and therefore allocate no memory at all (except in instruction space, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

static const int will be allocated once for the lifetime of program execution.

const int inside a functon will be allocated upon the stack every time entering a function and the deallocated from the stack upon exit.

I might point out the above "However, it's likely that the compiler will convert your code to this:" is not correct.  If you request "static" storage class, no compiler is going to ignore that, a static variable can counted on to be in memory for passing around pointers --- among other reasons.

Comment: If the OP's code is literally as written, then it can indeed be "converted" as in my answer.

Comment: And my gcc (4.6.2) and clang (3.0) eliminate it from `-O` onward.

Comment: True.  I suppose I was more addressing the storage class issue angle of the question rather than the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, they mean the same, and as mentioned by @Oli, compiler will optimize it such that the actual code may not even have it in final code.

But here is the different use case:-

```
int func1(int v) {
 const int c_i = compute_some_things(v);/* calculate the c_i everytime we enter this function */
 return c_i = v + c_i;
}


int func2(int e) {
 static const int c_i = compute_some_things_one_time();/* c_i is calculated ONCE, the next time, the value of c_i is retained every time the function is entered */
 return c_i = e + c_i;
}
```

Comment: This use case I already knew of, I was wondering about memory consumption when defining "real" constants.